# Superclass of bytes and bytearray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I'm making a function which will accept either an Unicode string or a bytes (or bytearray) object. I want to make sure only those types get passed. I know I can check whether something is a string by doing `isinstance(x, str)`, and I know I can write `isinstance(x, bytes) or isinstance(x, bytearray)`.

Is there a more concise way to check the latter, i.e., is there a class from which both `bytes` and `bytearray` derive?

Comment: Why not accept other types that support the requirements of your function as well? Why explicitly check for the type?

Comment: @Jim: Well, I don't know. I'm trying to implement (as an exercise) LZW compression for any binary data. What other types would it make sense to accept?

Comment: For example NumPy arrays.  Or the C extension type the user of your library just wrote himself.  You just don't know what type this might be useful for.  Try to work with what you get -- your code will fail anyway if the type doesn't fulfil the requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no common base class except for `object`:

```
>>> bytearray.__base__
<class 'object'>
>>> bytes.__base__
<class 'object'>
```

Don't check for the type.  Let the user pass parameters of whatever type she desires.  If the type does not have the required interface, your code will fail anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
isinstance(x, (bytes, bytearray))
```

However, [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) might be useful, so other types not deriving from bytes or bytearray, but implementing the right methods could be passed to the function.

Comment: You need additional parentheses: `isinstance(x, (bytes, bytearray))`.

Answer (score 2):

It does not make sense to accept Unicode strings, as they are under no circumstances binary data. I would probably accept any sort of sequence, and raise an error if any item in that sequence is not an integer between 0 and 255 (which you'll probably discover during the compression).

If you want to support Python 2, you also need to accept strings as a special case, as that is the binary type for Python 2.

Comment: I understand they're not binary data, but I thought it made sense to accept strings because someone might want to compress text. The function checks for this case and decodes the string to its UTF-8 binary representation.

Comment: @Javier Badia: If they want to compress text they should encode it first. Compressing Chinese text encoded into UTF8 is for example quite pointless, as UTF-16 will be a more efficient encoding. And compressing English text in UTF-16 encoding would be equally silly.